# How can I automate inserting <p></p> tags after paragraphs?

Tags: vim, macros

I often edit essays in Vim, and I would like to write a macro to insert <p> tags at the beginning and ends of paragraphs (defined as any chunk of text separated from other chunks of text by two or more line breaks). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
exe "%s#\\n\\n#\r</p>\r\r<p>#|norm D/<\/p\<CR>dd"
```

I would recommend looking into [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) if you do a lot of plain text essay writing. Also, the [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin by Tim Pope allows for this kind of tag surrounding. For instance, I can do `ysiptp<CR>` with the [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin to surround a paragraph with `<p>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up just using Markdown. +1 and accepted.